# How to incoporate ffmpeg in my audio input upload form

Tags: php, database, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

this is not really a question but a request to point me to any starting direction.
i have a simple audio upload form which stores the audio to a database or just any folder.
I want to start by implementing ffmpeg so before this audio is stored in the folder, it goes through ffmpeg(converted to mp3 for example) and stores the converted version to the folder.
Can someone please point me to any tutorial or links where i can start more research. 
I already installed ffmpeg.exe in xampp
much appreciated in advance

Comment: Before I can answer your question for ffmpeg: Do you already have a webpage with an upload form? If yes, which (server side) technology you are using? PHP, CGI, ..? xampp is just a package with a web server, so to get code running in your server, you need some scripts in your server.

Comment: hi Uwe,yes i do have a simple file upload form with scripts running in xampp. just a basic upload form for practice as i know implementing ffmpeg is gonna be a long road so i am very ready just to start researchin. asume a basic upload form like  <form id="uploadform" action="audio.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadframe"> and offcourse there are other php files and scripts that handle the upload and transfer, i just want to know where to start and i can start walking my way up and definitely ask if i run into trouble.thanks@Uwe Mannl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1: call ffmpeg.exe

If you are using PHP, you can call ffmpeg from your script like this:

```
$answer = shell_exec("ffmpeg.exe -i input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 output.mp3");
echo $answer."</br>";
```

In this case, ffmpeg.exe and your input file (input.wav in my case) must be in the same folder as your php script, or you set the directory relative to it.

`input.wav` can be any other file, ffmpeg doesn't really care about it, as long as it is a usual audio file.

Documentation about shell_exec: http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php

Information about mp3 encoding can be found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3

## Option 2: use PHP library

There are several php librarys for ffmpeg. But most of them are no longer maintened.

You could try this one: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

There is a good documentation, but I don't have any experiences with it.

Comment: holy shit. how simple. works like a boss. I just need to make some few adjustments in my script. thanks. need to explore again and see what other functions ffmpeg can do. thanks @uwe Mannl

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite No problem! Glad I could help ;)